# ListPreference how to get onClick event for already selected item?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I have a ListPreference, and I need to make some action after choosing an item,
**even if it is the selected item**

I try with this event:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) {...
```

but I got it only if I select other items.

Thanks for helping me.